# How do Service / SourceProviders work in Eclipse 4 RCP 2.0?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I've been busily getting with the future and migrating an old eclipse 3.7 application over to Eclipse 4 and whilst I'm happy with the application model for porting all the views I have a number of source providers that I am unsure about porting wise. I've been using a few tutorials on Eclipse 4 including [this Tutorial from good old Lars](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#tutorial_maps) but none seem to cover this particular element.

For a small amount of Context my existing application has a few classes extending **AbstractSourceProvider** that are registered in the **org.eclipse.ui.services** extension point. My views register themselves as listeners to these services using the `ISourceProviderService.getSourceProvider(key)` function from the workbench and update themselves if that source fires a sourced changed event. I also have a few providers that reference each other some times too so I'm wondering if this will still work with injection.

What sort of model is used in Eclipse 4?, should I just use the same old extension point? Can these extension point services be injected in to the views in the new cool anotationy way?

What gives?

Comment: Which extension points are you talking about?

Comment: The services sourceProvider functionality. org.eclipse.ui.services

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui.services` isn't available in a pure e4 application. In fact none of the code using source providers is part of e4.

Comment: Yes I had gotten that far, the question is what on earth do I do instead? I could just put it all in to singletons and make my own listener interfaces but what's the point of that, feels like going backwards.

Comment: Services can be put in the Eclipse Context in a number of ways and then just injected. Events can be broadcast on the Event Broker and handled using injection with @EventTopic.

Comment: What are these number of ways though, I can find no material on achieving this worthy goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a service in a number of ways:

Create an instance of your service class and put it in the `IEclipseContext`. This is often done in an 'Addon':

```java
public class MyAddon
{
  @PostConstruct
  void postConstruct(IEclipseContext context)
  {
    MyService myService = ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyService.class, context);

    context.put(MyService.class, myService);
  }
}
```

The 'Addon' is declared in the application.e4xmi file.

You could also create the service like this in the [LifeCycle](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html) class for the RCP.

An [OSGi service](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGiServices/article.html) will automatically be added to the Eclipse context.

You can use a [Context Function](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4ContextFunctions/article.html) which uses an OSGi service but doesn't create the actual service until it is needed.

In all cases you reference the service by injection:

```java
@Inject
MyService myService;
```

Note that injection is only done on objects created by Eclipse from objects described in the application.e4xmi. It is possible to do injection on other objects using `ContextInjectionFactory`.

Comment: Thanks for this, really useful, if I use an Addon to do it can those services have injection? The other feature of Eclipse 3 I use with these services is to have menu items that become disabled when certain source values change, how would one replicate this behaviour with the concept of source providers?

Comment: I have changed the AddOn example to create the service with ContextInjectionFactory so it can use injection. Menu item visiblity and enablement is done with 'core expressions' (org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions) and the handler @CanExecute method.